# Warum steht die Ortsangabe zwischen dem Prädikat und dem Subjekt?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

In einer Übung aus dem Buch "Erkundungen Deutsch als Fremdsprache B2 Kurs- und Arbeitsbuch‎" ist es erforderlich, aus dem vorgegebenen Wörtern Sätze im Präteritum zu bilden.

Für diese Worte: ***Anfang, 19. Jahrhundert***, ***Deutschland***, ***der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte***, ***entstehen***, sieht die offizielle Lösung so aus.

**Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts entstand *in Deutschland* der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte.**

Warum steht die Ortsangabe "in Deutschland" zwischen dem Prädikat und dem Subjekt?

Sollte die nicht vor dem Prädikat oder nach dem Subjekt stehen?

Answer (score 4):

> Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts entstand der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte in Deutschland.
>   Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts in Deutschland entstand der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte.

Beide Sätze sind auch möglich, legen aber die gefühlte Betonung stark auf dieses "in Deutschland", im zweiten Fall sogar auf die Kombination von Zeit und Ort. Der Leser wundert sich dann unter Umständen, warum das betont wird. Deswegen gibt es die Normalform, wo die Ortsangabe zwischen Prädikat und Subjekt steht, die dann auch jeder als unbetont empfindet. Der Grund, warum gerade das die Normalform ist, lässt sich nicht erklären. Das hat sich einfach irgendwann so eingebürgert.

Answer (score 3):

Die *offizielle* Lösung ist nur eine von mehreren, die gleichermaßen gültig sind. Der Satz soll transportieren, was wann wo passiert ist. Wegen der unpersönliche Konstruktion *es enstand*, gibt es keine deutlich beste Reihenfolge. (Das wäre anders bei: *Die Deutschen schenkten sich ab Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts... Zuckerstangen*.)

Da etwas typischerweise nur einmal **entsteht** (bei immateriellen Dingen, wie Erfindungen oder Bräuchen ist das nicht zwingend, aber das ist in so einem kurzen Satz nicht zu formulierbar) fällt das Hauptargument *das Wichtigste zuerst* weg: wenn der Brauch in einem anderen Land früher entstanden wäre, würde man nicht mehr *entstehen* sondern eher *sich verbreiten* formulieren.

Aus meiner Sicht kann die beste Reihenfolge für diesen Satz nur mit Kontext bestimmt werden. Weil der bei einem isolierten Beispielsatz ausfällt, kann man sich eine Reihenfolge aussuchen.

Comment: *Entstehen* ist nicht unpersönlich, der Brauch ist das Subjekt. *Das Wichtigste zuerst* erscheint mir keine Wortstellungsregel des Deutschen.

Answer (score 2):

Im Deutschen gibt es keine super strikte Regelung für die Ordnung von Satzgliedern.

Folgende Kombinationen sind möglich:

> A) Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts entstand in Deutschland der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte.
>   B) Der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte entstand Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts in Deutschland.
>   C) In Deutschland entstand Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte.
>   D) Der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte entstand in Deutschland Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts.

In A) und B) ist Bedeutung, dass der Brauch in Deutschland entstanden ist und zwar im 19. Jahrhundert. In C) und D) ist es ähnlich, aber es könnte sein, dass der Brauch schon woanders früher stattgefunden hat.

Comment: Kannst Du vielleicht noch in einem Satz erklären, WARUM diese Kombinationen möglich sind? So wie sie ist, geht die Antwort nämlich -mMn- an der Frage knapp vorbei...

Comment: Syntaktische Konstruktionen *haben* keine Begründungen, sondern nur Vorkommen. Man sieht das daran, dass andere Sprachen andere Konstruktionen erlauben, ohne dass ein inhaltlich haltbarer Grund dafür zu erkennen wäre.

Comment: @KilianFoth "Warum ist mein Satz falsch?" – "Weil er nicht vorkommt." Man kann auf Generalisierungen über Vorkommen zurückgreifen. Warum ist *heute ich gehe spazieren* falsch? Weil das finite Verb in Sätzen solchen Typs auf Position 2 erscheint.

Comment: Mit "warum" meinte ich ja auch nur einen Satz nach dem Motto: In der deutschen Sprache ist die Reihenfolge der Satzbestandteile nicht so fest vorgegeben wie in anderen Sprachen (SPO- Reihenfolge in englisch), sondern kann abweichen, je nachdem welchen Satzbestandteil man betonen möchte...

Comment: Hab einen Satz hinzugefügt.

Comment: Es gibt noch weitere zulässige Varianten, allerdings nun mit Perfekt (nicht Präteritum): **Entstanden ist der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte im 19. Jahrhundert in Deutschland.** und **Entstanden ist der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte in Deutschland im 19. Jahrhundert.** Hier liegt jeweils eine Betonung auf dem Element am Satzende.

Answer (score 0):

> Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts entstand in Deutschland der Brauch mit der
> Zuckertüte.

Ich bin da viel strenger. Diese "offizielle" Version ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, wie Sprache den Inhalt verschleiern kann. So will man sich nicht festlegen. Was in diesem Fall wohl historisch das beste ist.

> Der Brauch mit der Zuckertüte entstand Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts in Deutschland.

So sagt man aus, wann und wo der Brauch entstanden ist (ich wähle das perfekt). Man kann auch den Ort vor die Zeit stellen. Wenn man "zum Glück", "leider" oder "nicht" hinzufügt, wird es kompliziert und schnell zweideutig.

---

Hier ein Beispiel, wo es drauf ankommt, was man meint:

> 1936 fand in Deutschland die erste Olympiade statt. `???`
>
> 1936 fand die erste Olympiade in Deutschland statt. `?, aber wahr`
>
> Die erste Olympiade fand 1936 in Deutschland statt. `klar, aber falsch`